# What does ${sys:logger.out.type} mean in Log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am currently working on tidying up the logs for an internal tool we have. I came across the use of `${sys:logger.out.type}` inside the `Logger`s in `log4j2.xml`.

Here's a copy of our `log4j2.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="OFF">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">..
            <PatternLayout pattern="..."/>
        </Console>
        
        <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="${sys:microservice.log}" filePattern="${sys:microservice.log}.%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>...</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="300 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="${sys:logger.out.type}"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core" level="off" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="${sys:logger.out.type}"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" level="off" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="${sys:logger.out.type}"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.myOrgName" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="${sys:logger.out.type}"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="${sys:logger.out.type}"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

In my previous StackOverflow question, a very kind user redirected me to the Log4j [Property Substitution](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) page to better understand the semantics of `${sys:logger.out.type}`.

After reading through the documentation, I understand the `sys` Prefix is referring to a system property but don't quite understand what `logger.out.type` means?

Taking a stab here, is it referring to the output type of a `Logger`? Which could mean it's referring to the `Console` element named `stdout`?

Appreciate any insights & feedback from the community. Should any of my understanding be mistaken, please correct me, I am also learning :) Thank you!

Comment: I'm *guessing* that would be `System.getProperty("logger.out.type")`; *sys* indicating that it's a system property, and *logger.out.type* being the property key to be looked up.

Comment: You have two appenders, named `"stdout"` and `"FILE"`. That config allows you to choose between them at runtime by setting that system property.

Comment: The actual name used for the system property is not significant -- `<appender-ref ref="${sys:xyzzy}"/>` would work just as well, as long as you set a different system property.

Comment: hi friends, thanks for your quick & detailed responses:
@tgdavies Could you clarify a bit on your first comment -- about setting that system property? I'm not quite I follow what you explained. How do I set said system property?

Comment: You set system properties with a command line parameter to the JVM, for instance: `java -Dlogger.out.type=FILE  ...your other parameters...`

Comment: @tgdavies oh okay i get it! thank you so much! i'm using STS, just checked the "Run Configuration" & one of the arguments passed into the JVM is `-Dlogger.out.type=stdout`
Could you post your comment as an answer? i'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property like `${sys:logger.out.type}` in a log4j 2.x configuration file resolves to the value of the Java system property named `logger.out.type`.

You set system properties by passing the command line argument `-Dlogger.out.type=stdout` (or more generally `-D<property name>=<value>`) to the JVM when you invoke the `java` command.

You can also provide defaults, so `${sys:logger.out.type:-FILE}` would choose your `FILE` appender if no value was set for that system property.

Comment: that `${sys:logger.out.type:-FILE}` tip is really neat, thanks for sharing!